# Is there a way to get the decision trees used by machine learning methods like `RandomForest`?

Tags: machine-learning, implementation-details

I was looking at a [tutorial](https://github.com/SimFin/simfin-tutorials/blob/master/09_Machine_Learning.ipynb) of SimFin, a new German-based financial data provider.

There is a nice example of machine learning using `sklearn` in python. The package also has a function called `export_text` which is used in this tutorial (In [30]) to visualize one of the decision trees generated by the regression process based on the `RandomForest` method.

I see in the documentation that Mathematica supports this method for its high-level machine learning functions, `Classify` and `Predict`.

But is there a way to get to see the underlying decision trees being used by the method in Wolfram language as well?